# `match goal` doesn't match let destructuring expression

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm trying to prove a theorem involving a function that uses a destructuring `let` expression, and am trying to use the `match goal` tactic to destruct the right hand side, but for some reason the pattern doesn't match like I'd expect it to:

```
match goal with
  (* why doesn't this match? *)
  | [ |- context[let _ := ?X in _] ] => destruct X
end.
```

Here's a code snippet that should be runnable, if you have `Cpdt` from [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/repo) (I'm a huge convert to his style of automation).

I have found a proof, but I'm planning on proving many more theorems with a similar shape, and I'd like to have an automated tactic capable of proving many of them.

```
Set Implicit Arguments. Set Asymmetric Patterns.
Require Import List Cpdt.CpdtTactics.
Import ListNotations.

Section PairList.
  Variable K V: Set.
  Variable K_eq_dec: forall x y: K, {x = y} + {x <> y}.
  Variable V_eq_dec: forall x y: V, {x = y} + {x <> y}.

  Definition Pair: Type := (K * V).
  Definition PairList := list Pair.
  (* ... *)

  Fixpoint set (l: PairList) (key: K) (value: V): PairList :=
    match l with
    | [] => [(key, value)]
    | pr::l' => let (k, _) := pr in
      if K_eq_dec key k then (key, value)::l' else pr::(set l' key value)
    end.

  Theorem set_NotEmpty: forall (before after: PairList) key value,
    after = set before key value -> after <> [].
  Proof.
    intros before after. induction before.
    - crush.
    - intros. rewrite -> H. simpl.

      (* the context at this step:
        1 subgoal

          K, V : Set
          K_eq_dec : ...
          V_eq_dec : ...
          a : Pair
          before : list Pair
          after : PairList
          IHbefore: ...
          key : K
          value : V
          H : ...
          ============================
          (let (k, _) := a in
           if K_eq_dec key k
           then (key, value) :: before
           else
            a :: set before key value) <> []
      *)

      (* a successful proof
        destruct a.
        destruct (K_eq_dec key k); crush.
      *)

      match goal with
        (* why doesn't this match? *)
        | [ |- context[let _ := ?X in _] ] => destruct X
        | [ |- context[(() <> [])] ] => idtac X
      end.
      (* the above command prints this:
        (let (k, _) := a in
         if K_eq_dec key k
         then (key, value) :: before
         else
          a :: set before key value)
      *)
  Qed.
End PairList.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructuring lets are actually matches, so you need to look for a `match`. When a tactic doesn't match, you can see all expressions in your goal desugared with `Set Printing All.`

```
      match goal with
        | [ |- context[let _ := ?X in _] ] => destruct X
        (* ADD THIS LINE *)
        | [ |- context[match ?X with _ => _ end]] => destruct X
        | [ |- context[(() <> [])] ] => idtac X
      end.
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you! I am curious though, is there some underlying reason why `match goal` works with `if` statements and not let statements? This line works when an if is encountered `| [ |- context[if ?X then _ else _] ] => destruct X`, and my understanding is that if statements are also sugar for a `match`.

Comment: Li-Yao xia started his message with "destructuring lets are ..."  The notation you used in your question is for a plain let, not a destructuring one.  There are two kinds of `let` constructs, and only one of them is sugar for a match.